# Windows Callback, When The Active Window Changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7

```
public class ActiveWindow
{
public delegate void ActiveWindowChangedHandler(object sender, String windowHeader,IntPtr hwnd);
public event ActiveWindowChangedHandler ActiveWindowChanged;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
    IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread,
    uint dwmsEventTime);

const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax,
    IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc,
    uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

IntPtr m_hhook;
private WinEventDelegate _winEventProc;

public ActiveWindow()
{
    _winEventProc = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc);
    m_hhook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
        EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, IntPtr.Zero, _winEventProc,
        0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
}

void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd,
    int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    if (eventType == EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND)
    {
        if (ActiveWindowChanged != null)
            ActiveWindowChanged(this,GetActiveWindowTitle(hwnd),hwnd);
    }
}

private string GetActiveWindowTitle(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(500);
    GetWindowText(hwnd, Buff, Buff.Capacity);
    return Buff.ToString();
}

~ActiveWindow()
{
    UnhookWinEvent(m_hhook);
}
}
```

when i switch between the active windows i get the callback 
but when i maximize a minimized window i don't get a call back,

i find a work throw to solve this problem, but i am seeking for better solution

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/328990/SetWinEventHook-and-GetWindowText-Problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> when i switch between the active windows i get the callback but when i maximize a minimized window i don't get a call back

Yes, you need to use either the `EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART` or `EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND` [event constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066.aspx) to receive notification of window objects being minimized.

Use the `eventMin` and `eventMax` parameters of the [`SetWinEventHook` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) to indicate that you're interested in receiving notifications for one of these events *and* `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND`.